# How to grant all privileges to specific user to remote ip

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

This command work

```
GRANT ALL ON hmremote.* TO 'uber'@'localhost';
```

but this don't

```
GRANT ALL ON hmremote.* TO 'uber'@'111.111.111.111';
```

> ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

Also tried with.

```
GRANT ALL ON hmremote.* TO 'uber'@'111.111.111.111' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use `CREATE USER uber@159.69.63.196` before you can grant permissions to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CREATE USER uber@111.111.111.111` before you grant permissions.